# Encrypting Messages using secret key larger then the Key Size

Tags: encryption, secret-key

In order to encrypt messages larger than the key size (with secret keys), one needs to run the encryption operation separately over key size chunks of the message.

Is this statement True or False?

Comment: It's too vague; it depends on the cipher involved.

Comment: If the given answer solved your problem, you may [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) it. If it didn't, then please expand on what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The statement that you presented is definitely **false**.

**The following statement is true for RSA:**

> In order to encrypt messages larger than the key size (with *public key*), one needs to run the encryption operation separately over key size chunks of the message.

Although, this sort of chunked RSA encryption is a very bad idea.

**The following statement is true for block ciphers with some kind of [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation):**

> In order to encrypt messages larger than the *block size*, one needs to run the encryption operation separately over *blocks of the (padded)* message.

Key size and block size are two properties that are unrelated. DES is a cipher where the key size is smaller than the block size. AES is a cipher where the key size is equal to or larger than the block size.